# mysql service does not start

Tags: mysql, service, centos, daemon

The Mysql service on my newly set up development server does not start!

It is running on CentOS 5.

Every time I restart the service, it tells me that MySQL Daemon failed to start.

I have checked in the error log and this is what I see being repeated:

> *"110801 11:28:16 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
>       196 110801 11:36:14 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql 
>       197 110801 11:36:14 [Warning] '--log_slow_queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ''--slow_query_log'/'--slow_query_log_file'' instead.
>       198 ^G/usr/libexec/mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/binary_log.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
>       199 110801 11:36:14 [ERROR] Aborting"*

mysql.sock file is located inside /var/lib/mysql but when I view the file, it is empty.

owner of the mysql related files is mysql and permissions are 660 or higher.

edit: I have also uninstalled and reinstalled mysql and that did not solve it either.

I am pretty damn stumped! Can anyone help?
Mind you, I'm no expert, so if there's something obvious I have missed, punch me where it won't bruise.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: IT'S BEEN SOLVED!!! It turns out, I had played with the permissions on all files, but on my.cnf. It was set to 755 and that stopped it from being accessed. I switched it to 777 and the service started!! If someone can suggest alternatives to this solution, however, I'm all ears.
(Now I can go and have breakfast...)
M.

Comment: It's always a permissions problem ;) Great to hear you got it solved.

Comment: Actually, although that allowed me to start the service, I constantly get this warning now: Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/my.cnf' is ignored
Any permissions other than 777 will eliminate that problem, but will not allow me to start the mysqld service.
I haven't pin pointed yet what this causes, but it can't be good.
Suggestions?

Comment: my.cnf should have permissions set to 644. Check this post for more: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/i-have-rhel-5-0-and-mysql-start-problem-my-mysql-server-doesnt-start-700553/#post3430610

Comment: That's what I have found in multiple sources. When setting it to 644, I go back to not being able to start the service.

Comment: Try setting the permission to 600. If that fails, make sure the right owner is set for mysql, as per previous link.

Comment: Tried the 600 and same thing. I also followed the instructions in that link to the T and still didn't solve it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. At this point, I only have 2 recommendations: try XAMPP or reinstall MySQL. Hope it works out for you!

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: The issue is this line: `/usr/libexec/mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/binary_log.index' not found (Errcode: 13) 199 110801 11:36:14 [ERROR] Aborting`